# Rubymine project xml settings issues

Tags: rubymine

I have 2 issues with RubyMine settings I cannot be able to fix.

1. My project name, I changes .name property in .idea folder, but RubyMine is still using the old project name even after IDE restart. Where else this needs to be changed? Interestingly for example Wakatime (3th party time tracking tool) using RubyMine API sees the new name instead.
2. dataSources.local.xml. Postgres DB username for my local instance seems to change back to my current mac username every time I restart IDE causing errors. It does remember all the other settings like postgresql host and even the non standard port I use, but not the username. Is there some other place than dataSources.local.xml where it could be taking the username from.

Any help would be appreciated. So thanks in advance.

Comment: So finally solved this but going back to sublime text. IDE setups took more time then actual ruby code I had to write. Turns out that next to field where you add DB password in rubymine there is tick that is off by default it says save to disk. If not ticked your DB password settings are gone when you close the IDE